# How to read special characters (punctuation marks, hypens, colons) using scanf function?

Tags: c, character, special-characters, scanf

I wrote a little piece of code that would input address from the keyboard. However, I am not able to figure out how may I be able to read in special characters, such as hypen, colon etc. Can you please suggest some edit to my code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
       char address[80];


       printf("Enter address: ");
       scanf("%[a-z | A-Z | 0-9]", address); //How may I include characters like hypen.
       printf("\n\n%s\n\n", address);
}
```

Output that I am getting:

```
Enter Address: Plot No - 16, Palm Grooves, Nagpur - 440022, India

Plot No
```

No commas, no hyphen, no numeral is being displayed.

Thank you for your help and comments.

Comment: If you [knew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string) what your *existing* code does, specifically `scanf("%[a-z | A-Z | 0-9`, the answer would be obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I do realize what I am doing:

scanf("%[a-z| A-Z | 0-9]");

would allow to key in all the small characters a-z, capital letters A-z and numerals 0-9. I am just ignorant about adding the special characters....

Comment: That's good. But [to the format string there's nothing special about special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11794936/7724).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add them to the list of acceptable characters one by one, like this:

```
"%[a-z | A-Z | 0-9/,.-]"
```

Here is [this example on ideone](http://ideone.com/FVmIB).

Since you are using `scanf` into a buffer of limited size, it is a good idea to add a size constraint to the format specifier in order to avoid buffer overruns:

```
char address[81]; // One extra character for padding
printf("Enter address: ");
scanf("%80[a-z | A-Z | 0-9/,.-]", address); // %80 limits the input
printf("\n\n%s\n\n", address);
```

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborate answer.

Comment: This answer needs attention. Is not `"/-,"` a  range like `"a-z"`?  "special characters" include `']'`, `'^'`, `'-'`, `'\"'`which has their peculiarities in a scan set. Using `'-'` can lead to implementation defined behavior.  I'd write my own answer, but I think some mods to this one would be a better way to go.  Your thoughts?

Comment: @chux Thanks! When you see mistakes like that, feel free to edit them without asking, because it's definitely an error. Thank you!